# Linux Service unexpectedly died

Tags: linux, bash, service, daemon, systemctl

Running Ubuntu 17.04, I'd like to have a `systemctl` service which oversees a main `bash` script, where three programs (here substituted by dummy script `foo_script` tagged with an argument) run under an endless loop (because of possible program crashes).

The main script, `foo_main.sh`, works correctly if called from a command line; but the service I'm trying to set up from it crashes soon.

File `foo_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "FooScripting "$1 >> "foo.d/"$1
```

File `loop.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

nLoop=0
prgName=$1
prgArg=$2

echo "<< START of "${prgName} ${prgArg}" loop >>"

while :
do
    let nLoop=nLoop+1
    echo "<< looping "${prgName} ${prgArg}" >>" ${nLoop}
    "./"${prgName} ${prgArg}
    sleep 1
done

echo "<< END of "${prgName} ${prgArg}" loop >>"
```

File `foo_main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo_main start in "${PWD}

./loop.sh "foo_script.sh" "fb" &
sleep 2
./loop.sh "foo_script.sh" "gc" &
./loop.sh "foo_script.sh" "gb" &

echo "foo_main end"
```

File `/etc/systemd/system/food.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description = Foo Daemon
After = network.target

[Service]
Type = simple
# User = <<USER>>
# PIDFile=/var/food.pid
WorkingDirectory = /home/john/bin
ExecStart = /home/john/bin/foo_main.sh
# ExecStop = killall loop.sh
# ExecReload = killall loop.sh && /home/john/bin/foo_main.sh
# Restart = on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

What I obtain from every `sudo systemctl status food.service` (after a `start` ofc) is almost the same output

> ● food.service - Foo Daemon
>
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/food.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Active: inactive (dead)
>
> Sep 28 14:54:30 john-host systemd[1]: Started Foo Daemon.
>
> Sep 28 14:54:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7376]: foo_main script start in /home/john/bin
>
> Sep 28 14:54:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7376]: << START of foo_script.sh fb loop >>
>
> Sep 28 14:54:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7376]: << looping foo_script.sh fb >> 1
>
> Sep 28 14:54:31 john-host foo_main.sh[7376]: << looping foo_script.sh fb >> 2
>
> Sep 28 14:54:32 john-host foo_main.sh[7376]: foo_main script end
>
> Sep 28 15:24:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7921]: << START of foo_script.sh gb loop >>
>
> Sep 28 15:24:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7921]: << START of foo_script.sh gc loop >>
>
> Sep 28 15:24:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7921]: << looping foo_script.sh gb >> 1
>
> Sep 28 15:24:30 john-host foo_main.sh[7921]: << looping foo_script.sh gc >> 1

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: You are quoting exactly the wrong things. `foo.d/"$1"`, not `"foo.d/"$1`, although `"foo.d/$1"` is typically written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use `Type=oneshot` + `RemainAfterExit=yes` in your `/etc/systemd/system/food.service`

Look at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html to refer ***onshot*** type of service.

The service file like following should solve your issue too.

```
[Unit]
Description = Foo Daemon
After = network.target

[Service]
Type = oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
# User = <<USER>>
# PIDFile=/var/food.pid
WorkingDirectory = /home/john/bin
ExecStart = /home/john/bin/foo_main.sh
# ExecStop = killall loop.sh
# ExecReload = killall loop.sh && /home/john/bin/foo_main.sh
# Restart = on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved... the service was stopped simply because its execution flow ended with `foo_main.sh`. It was enough to add something like

```
# ...
./loop.sh "foo_script.sh" "endless_dummy_loop"
```

**Without** background ampersand, at the end of `foo_main.sh`.

Clearly real services are far different from this, but I got the point now.